# Converting decimal to Date

Tags: sql, date, casting, db2, db2-400

I have a column with dates formatted as decimals, for example: 20,210,830.

I want to convert this number to date format as `08/30/2021`

I have tried to use convert and the database shoots me an error that convert is not a valid function. Cast seems to work but, only returns a null value every time.

This statement will validate:

```
SELECT CAST(CAST(CONTCLMPDTE AS VARCHAR(8)) AS DATE) 
FROM CMSFIL.JCTDSC AS COMPLDATE
```

This statement works but, just outputs null. For background I am querying from a Db2 database.

My ultimate goal is to use this converted date to grab the difference from the current day.

Such as

```
DAY(CURRENT_DATE) - DAY(COMPLDATE)
```

Comment: Why do you have dates as decimals? What does that representation mean?

Comment: Why not use the `db2` built-in `Date` data type?

Comment: I don't have control to change datatypes in the database I can only query from it. The developers from what I see, set most dates in decimal format and then with an unknown string ,to me, converted them to date.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after a long couple days and almost pulling my hair out, here is what worked for me.

```
SELECT date(substr(CONTCLMPDTE,1,4)||'-'||substr(CONTCLMPDTE,5,2)||'-'||substr(CONTCLMPDTE,7,2)) FROM JCTDSC WHERE COMPANYNUMBER={Company Number} AND JOBNUMBER={Job Number} LIMIT 1
```

This formatted from yyyymmdd to mm/dd/yyyy. It also worked for finding the days between current_date and CONTCLMPDTE using this code.

```
DAYS(CURRENT_DATE) - DAYS({COntract Compl Date Formatted})
```

Thank you all for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Converting it to a date, you  cqan do it like this

```
CREATE TABLE JCTDSC (
    CONTCLMPDTE varchar(10)
    
);
```

```
INSERT INTO JCTDSC VALUES ('20,220,830')
```

```
SELECT date(to_date(REPLACE(CONTCLMPDTE,',',''),'YYYYMMDD')) FROM JCTDSC AS COMPLDATE
```

| 1 |
| --- |
| 2022-08-30 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/kh3-D8dU)

Answer (score 0):

You probably get an error because you have some INT / DECIMAL value which can't be converted to a date using this pattern.
The solution is to create some "safe" conversion function "eating" errors like below.

```
CREATE FUNCTION DATE_SAFE (P_DT INT)
RETURNS DATE
CONTAINS SQL
NO EXTERNAL ACTION
DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN
  DECLARE EXIT HANDLER FOR SQLEXCEPTION 
    BEGIN 
        RETURN CAST (NULL AS DATE);
    END;
  RETURN DATE (TO_DATE (CAST (P_DT AS CHAR (8)), 'YYYYMMDD'));
END
```

Usage:

```
SELECT 
  CONTCLMPDTE
--, DATE (TO_DATE (CAST (CONTCLMPDTE AS CHAR (8)), 'YYYYMMDD'))
, DATE_SAFE (CONTCLMPDTE)
FROM (VALUES 0, 20220830) T (CONTCLMPDTE)
```

The function returns NULL if the corresponding INT can't be converted to a DATE, and no error is thrown as in case, when you uncomment the commented out line with built-in functions only.

Comment: his date is 20,220,830. and not 20220830

Comment: I understood the "dates formatted as decimals" phrase as "the column has decimal data type". It would be very strange if it has VARCHAR (10) data type, since OP tries to cast it as VARCHAR (8).

Comment: dbb2 doesn allow decimal in that format, the commas are tthousands separators, so the user interprets them as decimqals

Comment: OP provides the value as it appeared in their favourite tool probably, which applies such a formatting. But it would be really nice if OP provided the column data type explicitly to avoid guessing...

Comment: When I tried running one conversion before the error it through me was "Integer cannot be converted to date." The reason I say its a decimal is because in the DBeaver it allocates it as data type "decimal." Sorry if this is confusing I am new to SQL as a whole.

Comment: @MarkBarinstein So I tried this code and I get this error SQ20448 - Expression not valid using format string specified for TIMESTAMP_FORMAT.

Comment: @onexcent What's your Db2 platform and version?

Comment: @MarkBarinstein it looks like I'm running IBM I Version 7. I did end up figuring it out but, I am sure I will be back with more questions as I have only been doing SQL for about two months. Thanks for all your help!

Comment: @onexcent Look at the updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

The value just need to be converted into a string with a date format. Then you can use the date() function to convert to date.

```
create table qtemp/dec_vals (
        col1  decimal(8,0)  );

insert into qtemp/dec_vals
values (20200830),  (20200831),  (20200901),  (20200902),  (20200903),  (20200904),  (20200905),  (20200906);

select date(substr(char(col1), 5, 2) || '/' || substr(char(col1), 7, 2) || '/' || substr(char(col1), 1, 4))  from qtemp/dec_vals;
```